# Texstudio autocomplete cite key by full text search?

Tags: bibliographies, texstudio, auto-completion

I am using Texstudio 2.12.6 on Mac.

When typing `\cite{somewords`, autocomplete shows a list of cite keys that start with 'somewords'. But I want it to show cite keys that contain 'somewords' inside, for example if cite key is `[author][title][year]`, then 'somewords' could be author's name (at the beginning) or paper's title (inside).

How to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Not possible currently. Maybe file a feature request at the [project Github page](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues).

Comment: Feature request open: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/132

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality has been added since TXS 2.12.12, called fuzzy autocomplete. Activate it as the default from the options:

```
Configure TeXstudio -> Completion -> Preferred commands list (set to fuzzy)
```

[image]

Result:

[image]

So if you type `ton`, entries like `benton2012`, `thompson2017` will appear in the suggestion box. 
It will work with cross-references, commands etc. as well.

---

Notes from OP (@THN):

1. We need to press "Enter" at `\cite{bibid}` to get in cite key autocomplete mode;
2. Autocomplete is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks. For new users, note that: 1. We need to press "Enter" at `\cite{bibid}` to get in cite key autocomplete mode; 2. Autocomplete is case-sensitive. Hope it helps.

Comment: @THN thanks, those are good points. added it to the answer for posterity.